# How can I get live data from Tableau when combining web connector and cloud sources?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Tableau making extract from web connector and cloud data.

I am working on Tableau to create visualization plots, I am getting an encrypted data from the web connector and cloud data (live) from microsoft sql server. When I add both of these data sources and make connections(table connections) it saves it as the extract. Can someone tell is this extract due to web connector? because as extract is snapshot of data, I want data from both these sources and it should be refreshed as new row is being added. I have published the extract and tried to schedule it but it is not refreshing the data as I mentioned it is just a snapshot. What changes I do to get the live data or is this due to web connector issues?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a Web Data Connector (WDC) in Tableau it must be an extract.

Comment: So that means I have to refresh the extract manually and publish it on tableau online everytime ?